# Retrieving ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to accomplish the following task:

> Ask the user for a number, if this number is 2 or greater, save it into an array length. Then ask the user to input strings depending on the number written before (done), and finally display each of the inputted strings before to complete a two-dimensional array*

```
// (the length [z] was already defined before)

String arrayer[] = new String[z];
for(multi=0; multi<arrayer.length; multi++){

    do {
        out.print("\n");
        out.print("Enter the name of [Subject "+(multi+1)+"] : ");
        try {
            arrayer[multi]=LeerTeclado.nextLine();  
            if (arrayer[multi].length()>15){
                out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------");
                out.println("Name of subject should be max. 15 characters long");
                out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
                continue;
            }
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            out.println("Subject name should be shorter than 15 characters\n");
            LeerTeclado.next();
        }
    } while ( true );   
}

// Where `arrayer[z].length` should display the **name** of the subject and increase depending on the number of subjects entered

int[][] mat;
mat=new int[z][n];

for (int u=0; u < arrayer.length ; u++) {
    for (int f=0; f < arrayer.length; f++) {
        out.print ("\nWrite your average grade of " + arrayer[z].length + ": ");
        mat[u][f] = LeerTeclado.nextInt();
    }       
}
```

Comment: What difficulties do you encounter? What's the problem?

Comment: I can't make it to display "Write your average grade of (name of subject). Name of subject won't appear, I know there's something I'm doing wrong, but I would appreciate a little help.

Comment: Another thing: `" where arrayer[z].length should display the name of the subject and increase depending on the number of subjects entered"` - you realize that `arrayer[z].length` is the _length_ of the string (and the call should be `length()` to compile) and thus can't "display the name", don't you?

Comment: yes, but otherwise I would get this when compiling:

Write your average grade of [Ljava.lang.String;@2503dbd31

Comment: If you just use `arrayer[z]` and you still get the output of `Array#toString()` (that's what you seem to get), `arrayerz` seems to be a two dimensional array - however, I assume you just used `arrayer` without the index.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `arrayer` is an array of `String` objects, which are the names of subjects, just use `out.print("\nWrite your average grade of " + arrayer[f] + ": ");`, i.e. without the `length()` method.

Additionally, `z` doesn't seem to be defined, so you'd need to either define it or use one of the outer loop's variables `u` or `f`, as I already did in the line above.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at VecMat.main(VecMat.java:211)

Comment: @AlbertoLopezRodriguez well, you might try and debug what index is out of bounds. If you use the code as posted in your question and just use `u` or `f` you should not get that exception. This indicates you didn't post the actual code or didn't follow the instructions. A hint for asking questions here: put some effort into the questions and your comments. Just posting exceptions doesn't count as such.